# 30 minutes warm up

Tags: warm-up

Bodyweight athletes tend to spend a lot of time training, whilist the classic bodybuilder has quick 45 minutes sessions...a bodyweight athlete invests at least 30 minutes of training just for warming up. As seen by Sergio Di Pascquale, Arthur Zanetti, Bartek kruk, Manuel Caruso, Ruslan Saibov and many others.

All of them thend to warm up for long periods, and then train for hours.

I'm pretty sure even powerlifters or weightlifters invest long periods just to warm up properly so it is a common thing.

I myself noticed that my physical capacities are pathetic, comparable to the average bodybuilder when I skip the warm up or try to shorten it. But when warmed up properly I can display all my strength with no problem.

Now, a cultured person would just accept the fact that they can't be in their peak physical shape 24/7 without preparation.

But my curiosity pushes me to ask:

**is there a specific type of training which can be done outside of main sessions as preparations in order to adapt the body to be always fitter and require shorter warm ups?**

Like, if I invest my day off  to train my "readyness", would it be possible? Or does the body always require to be warmed up properly in order to exert their Maxim capacities?

In short: can you train to require less warming up time?

Answer (score 1):

There's several workout routines, so classic bodybuilders use 45 minute routines, but 6 days a week, where some use 60-90 minute routines 3 days a week. There isn't a solid routine that works for everyone.

There's 3 kind of warmups..
static: essentially stretching your muscles for 30 seconds
Dynamic: think arm circles, bodyweight lunges, jogging in place
Pre-exercise warmup: Doing 1-2 low weight, high rep(15-20 reps) of an exercise before you actually do the exercise, to increase blood flow.
Foam rolling-rolling muscles onto a foam roller. loosens muscles and stretches them.

To answer your question, you can stretch and work on your mobility by doing the static and dynamic stretches to keep your muscles active, although I think the best warmup for you will be to do a warmup set before each exercise which will shave off time off your workout. this also flushes your muscles with blood, "priming" them to start the exercise. you only need to do this for big compound exercises, although you can do it for regular compound exercises too, like a lat pulldown. a warmup shouldn't be 30 minutes, most bodybuilders use a 10 minute warmup with foam roller or dynamic stretching, and have a 5 minute cooldown after their workout.